How to display response from api in one component to other component in Angular 17
This is my service code:
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ResponseService {
  private responseDataSubject = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
  responseData$ = this.responseDataSubject.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  setResponseData(data: any) {
    console.log('Response data set:', data);
    this.responseDataSubject.next(data);
  }
}

This is my first component Typescript code:
this.http.post<any>('url link', requestBody)
      .subscribe({
        next: response => {
          console.log(response);
          this.loader.stop();
          // Store the response in the shared service
          this.responseService.setResponseData(response);
          
          // Redirect to MyprojectsComponent
          this.router.navigate(['/myprojects']);
        },
        error: error => {
          console.error('Error occurred:', error);
        }
      });

This is my Second component TS:
constructor(private router: Router,public responseService:ResponseService , private route:ActivatedRoute) { }
 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.responseService.responseData$.subscribe({
      next: (response) => {
        if (response !== null) {
          console.log('Response from ScribblePadComponent:', response);
          // Proceed with handling the response data
        } else {
          console.error('Response from ScribblePadComponent is null.');
        }
      },
      error: (error) => {
        console.error('Error fetching response from ScribblePadComponent:', error);
      }
    });
    this.fetchData(); // Initial data fetch

This is my Second component Html:
<div class="item pos-rel mob-style" *ngFor="let item of row.items">
  <div class="content-wrapper general-box-shadow" style="flex-wrap: wrap;">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="content">
        <div class="circle-container">
          <div class="number-circle">{{ item.id }}</div>
        </div>
        <div style="padding: 10px 74px;" class="list-cards" >
          <p style="font-size: 14px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, </p>
          <p *ngIf="item.collapsed">"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.</p>
          <!-- <button (click)="toggleDescription(item)" style="background-color: #e15ed2;"> {{getButtonName(item)}} </button>
          <button style="background-color: #a44de3;"> Related Movies </button>
          <button style="background-color: #ae81ff;"> Edit </button> -->
          <span (click)="toggleDescription(item)" class="f-16" title="Expand/Collapse">
            <i class="fas fa-chevron-down" [class.rot180]="item.collapsed"></i>
          </span>
          <span class="f-16" title="Related Movies"><i class="fas fa-film"></i></span>
          <span class="f-16" title="Edit"><i class="fas fa-pen"></i></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

Here is the sample response I am getting from API but it is not emitting to second component..it always shows null:
Response data set: {
    "logline_1": [
        "A street fighter battles for survival in the underground world of dog fights. When he refuses to kill a defeated opponent, he becomes the next target. Now, he must outsmart the syndicate to save his own life.",
        "Jake, a seasoned street fighter, dominates the gritty underground scene of dog fights. His moral compass is tested when he's ordered to kill a defeated rival, but he refuses. The syndicate running the fights marks him for death, thrusting him into a deadly game of cat and mouse. With the help of a former opponent turned ally, Jake devises a plan to dismantle the syndicate from within. As the final showdown looms, Jake's skills are put to the ultimate test. Will he survive the fight of his life, or will the syndicate claim another victim?",
        "Fight Club"
    ],
    "logline_2": [
        "An undercover cop infiltrates a brutal street fighting ring. Her mission turns deadly when she's ordered to fight to the death. She must expose the corrupt officials before her identity is revealed.",
        "Detective Sarah Connors goes deep undercover to bring down a notorious street fighting ring. She earns the trust of the organizers, but her cover is jeopardized when she's forced into a kill-or-be-killed match. Sarah's moral dilemma intensifies as she faces an innocent opponent in the ring. Time is running out as she scrambles to gather evidence against the corrupt officials behind the fights. With her identity on the brink of exposure, Sarah must make a life-changing decision. Can she maintain her cover and serve justice, or will the brutal world she's infiltrated consume her?",
        "Warrior"
    ],


Where do you set value to row.items?

It looks to me like you are confusing Observables and Behaviour subjects here.
Observable - A one time deal. Observe the result at the time of subscription
BehaviorSubject - Get an initial result (often null) but also receive any changes while subscribed
So I would change your service to this: -
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ResponseService {
public responseDataSubject = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);

  constructor() { }

  setResponseData(data: any) {
    console.log('Response data set:', data);
    this.responseDataSubject.next(data);
  }
}

Then just subscribe to the Behavior Subject ... no need for an Observable here
constructor(private router: Router,public responseService:ResponseService , private route:ActivatedRoute) { }
 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.responseService.responseDataSubject.subscribe({
      next: (response) => {
        if (response !== null) {
          console.log('Response from ScribblePadComponent:', response);
          // Proceed with handling the response data
        } else {
          console.error('Response from ScribblePadComponent is null.');
        }
      },
      error: (error) => {
        console.error('Error fetching response from ScribblePadComponent:', error);
      }
    });
    this.fetchData(); // Initial data fetch


I am still getting this in console console.error('Response from ScribblePadComponent is null.');

console.log('Response data set:', data); this is the output on console{
"logline_1": [
"A street fighter battles fo",
"Fight Club"
],

What should happen is that you will get "Response from ScribblePadComponent is null." when you initially subscribe.
If you are still subscribed to the Behavior Subject you should then get the data you are looking for ... the console message to say you've got it, followed by the entry to show it's set and finally the one that receives the  Behavior Subject's new value.
